# `df` command not capturing entire output in perl

Tags: linux, perl, unix, filesystems

I am writing a perl script which uses some fields from "df" command.

```
 my $command = "df -a";
 my $output = `$command`;
#   my $outputs = qx/df/;
  print "$output\n\n\n";
```

This is giving me output as follows-

```
Filesystem                                                              1K-blocks        Used   Available Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs                                                                     4096           8        4088   1% /dev
tmpfs                                                                    40925604          24    40925580   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                                                                     9864920        9180     9855740   1% /run
tmpfs                                                                        4096           0        4096   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda3                                                                20937708    12632092     8305616  61% /
/dev/sda2                                                                   20422        6266       14156  31% /boot/efi
/dev/sdb                                                                 41922560     5476428    36446132  14% /data
tmpfs                                                                     4932456           0     4932456   0% /run/user/0
bkpteam:/swdepot                                                        587202560   308491328   278711232  53% /mnt
tmpfs                                                                     4932456           0     4932456   0% /run/user/58037
server_name:/db_share/Restore_NewDB/ABC_import/trans              25163737088  2580348928 22583388160  11% /xyz/ABC/trans
```

However, when I execute "df -a" command directly on Linux, i am getting the following output-

```
Filesystem                                                             Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
proc                                                                      0     0     0    - /proc
sysfs                                                                     0     0     0    - /sys
devtmpfs                                                               4.0M  8.0K  4.0M   1% /dev
securityfs                                                                0     0     0    - /sys/kernel/security
tmpfs                                                                   40G   24K   40G   1% /dev/shm
devpts                                                                    0     0     0    - /dev/pts
tmpfs                                                                  9.5G  9.0M  9.4G   1% /run
tmpfs                                                                  4.0M     0  4.0M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
cgroup2                                                                   0     0     0    - /sys/fs/cgroup/unified
cgroup                                                                    0     0     0    - /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd
pstore                                                                    0     0     0    - /sys/fs/pstore
efivarfs                                                                  0     0     0    - /sys/firmware/efi/efivars
bpf                                                                       0     0     0    - /sys/fs/bpf
cgroup                                                                    0     0     0    - /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu,cpuacct
cgroup                                                                    0     0     0    - /sys/fs/cgroup/net_cls,net_prio
cgroup                                                                    0     0     0    - /sys/fs/cgroup/perf_event
cgroup                                                                    0     0     0    - /sys/fs/cgroup/freezer
cgroup                                                                    0     0     0    - /sys/fs/cgroup/blkio
cgroup                                                                    0     0     0    - /sys/fs/cgroup/misc
cgroup                                                                    0     0     0    - /sys/fs/cgroup/hugetlb
cgroup                                                                    0     0     0    - /sys/fs/cgroup/devices
cgroup                                                                    0     0     0    - /sys/fs/cgroup/memory
cgroup                                                                    0     0     0    - /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset
cgroup                                                                    0     0     0    - /sys/fs/cgroup/pids
cgroup                                                                    0     0     0    - /sys/fs/cgroup/rdma
/dev/sda3                                                               20G   13G  8.0G  61% /
systemd-1                                                                 -     -     -    - /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc
debugfs                                                                   0     0     0    - /sys/kernel/debug
mqueue                                                                    0     0     0    - /dev/mqueue
tracefs                                                                   0     0     0    - /sys/kernel/tracing
hugetlbfs                                                                 0     0     0    - /dev/hugepages
fusectl                                                                   0     0     0    - /sys/fs/fuse/connections
configfs                                                                  0     0     0    - /sys/kernel/config
none                                                                      0     0     0    - /run/credentials/systemd-sysusers.service
/dev/sda2                                                               20M  6.2M   14M  31% /boot/efi
/dev/sdb                                                                40G  5.3G   35G  14% /data
tracefs                                                                   0     0     0    - /sys/kernel/debug/tracing
tmpfs                                                                  4.8G     0  4.8G   0% /run/user/0
bkpteam:/swdepot                                                       560G  295G  266G  53% /mnt
tmpfs                                                                  4.8G     0  4.8G   0% /run/user/58037
binfmt_misc                                                               0     0     0    - /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc
/dev/sdb                                                                40G  5.3G   35G  14% /usr/FFF
/dev/sdb                                                                40G  5.3G   35G  14% /xyz/ABC
servername:/db_share/Restore_NewDB/ABC_import/trans                24T  2.5T   22T  11% /xyz/ABC/trans
```

Later on in the script, i have a regex which captures lines containing the either "/xyz/ABC" or "/usr/FFF".

You can see that "df" command, when ran in linux, contain 3 such lines as follows-

```
servername:/db_share/Restore_NewDB/ABC_import/trans                24T  2.5T   22T  11% /xyz/ABC/trans
/dev/sdb                                                                40G  5.3G   35G  14% /usr/FFF
/dev/sdb                                                                40G  5.3G   35G  14% /xyz/ABC
```

However, the 'df -a' output in perl script does not capture the last two lines mentioned in the expected results.
The filesystem in Linux is such that "/dev/sdb" has 3 mounts present on it and "df -a" executed vua perl script is able to capture only the first entry which does not contain either of the regex.

This is messing up with the flow of the script as we need the values "/xyz/ABC" or "/usr/FFF".
We don't directly use "/xyz/ABC" or "/usr/FFF" as ABC and FFF are script inputs and further used in other logic involving some nested paths.

Please help in the situation, how to capture the entire "df" output by perl script.

Comment: Is the df perl is executing the same one with the same options as you're running in your shell? Do you have it aliased?

Comment: Open a terminal, type `alias`, and press Enter. You probably have an alias for `df` that adds the `-h` flag or similar.

Comment: Can you try to put `command df -a` in both cases to see if you still have same result ?

Comment: Can also use `\df -a` to bypass the alias.

Comment: try with full path to df binary in both cases.

Comment: Perhaps use a module instead of playing the guessing game of parsing shell output [`Filesys::Df`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Filesys::Df).